# Problema ao definir 'allowTimes' no xdsoft DateTimePicker dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datetime

Bem galera, tô com um problema aqui com o [DateTimePicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/). Estou tentando definir os horários aceitos dinamicamente com o atributo allowTimes. Pra ficar mais fácil o código tá asism:

```
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    datepicker: false,
    format: 'H:i',
    onShow: function () {
        var id = $('#id').find('option:selected').val();
        var horarios = PegaHorarios(id);
        console.log("allowTimes:"+horarios);
        this.setOptions({
           allowTimes:horarios
        });
    }
});
```

Explicando rapidamente o código: Eu pego a 'id' pra fazer uma busca com a função PegaHorarios(), utilizando [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), coloquei o 'dataType' como 'script'(já tentei json, html nenhum funcionou), a função me retorna os valores corretamente, que testei via console.log:

> allowTimes:['14:00','14:20','14:40','15:00','15:20','15:40','16:00','16:20','16:40','17:00','17:20','17:40']

Então não sei o que fazer... Tentei algumas opções e nada, alguém tem alguma idéia de como consertar?

Obrigado.

A, só pra constar eu copiei e colei esse log na função e o código funcionou...

Edit 1:
Essa é a funcão PegaHorarios.

```
function PegaHorarios(id) {
var retorno = "";
carregando(true);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'script',
    url: 'includes/monta-horas.php',
    async: false, // não achei método alternativo
    // Valor default é true então essa opção é desnecessária agora - async: true,
    data: 'id='+id,
    success: function (response) {
        //console.log("Sucesso no envio da solicitação Ajax");
        //console.log(response);
        carregando(true);
        retorno = response;
    },
    error: function (response) {
        //console.log("Erro na Solicitação Ajax");
        //console.log(response);
        retorno = false;
    },
    complete: function (response) {
        //console.log("Solicitação Ajax Completada");
        //console.log(response);
        carregando(false);
    }

});
return retorno;
}
```

No caso o retorno vem de um código PHP que retorna a String que é mostrada no console.log.

```
//echo json_encode($retorno);
echo $retorno;
```

Usei o json_encode quando o dataType foi json e o resultado foi o mesmo.

Não lembro se tinha utilizado o JSON.parse [@Marconi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/13322/marconi), mas utilizei e não funcionou.

Edit 2:
Pra completar um resumo, ao mostrar a horas no datetimepicker eu chamo a função

```
   PegaHorarios()
```

com a value de um campo select através de

```
  $('#id').find('option:selected').val();
```

Já na função PegaHorarios() eu faço uma solicitação AJAX a uma página PHP que me retorna uma String com var_dump:

```
   string(97) "['14:00','14:20','14:40','15:00','15:20','15:40','16:00','16:20','16:40','17:00','17:20','17:40']"
```

Recebo essa string e retorno na função para a

```
var horarios;
```

Comment: Qual o retorno da função `PegaHorarios()`? Poste o código dela.

Comment: você já tentou dá um JSON.Parse(horarios)?

Comment: Editei com mais informações, @Marconi como disse ali em cima testei o JSON.parse mas não funcionou. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @RafaelFontenele você fez a inclusão do Jquery antes do datetimepicker? Fiz um teste aqui funciona tudo normal.

Comment: @Marconi, sim, é tanto que quando eu defino manualmente o allowTimes para allowTimes:['08:00'] (por exemplo) ela funciona. Achei que poderia ser o escopo da variavel horarios e tentei torná-la global, mas de nada adiantou :/. Obrigado novamente.

Comment: @RafaelFontenele tenta usar novamente o JSON.Parse(horarios), eu escrevi errado o "P" era maiúsculo, veja se dá algum erro de console.

Comment: Quando utilizo JSON.Parse diz:     Uncaught TypeError: JSON.Parse is not a function e quando uso JSON.parse diz:    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente resolvi isto. As alterações no código que fiz foram essas:

Primeiro de tudo no meu código PHP onde ele retornava uma String com todos os horários alterei para retornar um:

```
array()
$retorno = array();
```

onde cada horário é uma posição no array.

Depois disso removi o:

```
dataType: 'script',
```

que mesmo mudando para 'JSON' não funcionava, o que é estranho... Em seguida usei o

```
JSON.parse(horarios)
```

que quando usava o dataType como JSON dava erro.

Então fiz uma:

```
var teste = JSON.parse(horarios);
```

E usei no final:

```
this.setOptions({
       allowTimes:teste
    });
```

E agora finalmente funciona. Vlw!

Resumindo o problema de tudo isso se deve ao fato do allowTimes receber um array e não uma string.